# How to emulate titletoc with tocloft

Tags: table-of-contents, line-breaking, tocloft

I was using `titletoc` until I realized that it has some incompatibilities with `hyperref`. The thing is, that `titletoc` can do the same thing in a easier way, less one.

```
\titlecontents*{subsection}[5.4em]
{\small}
{\thecontentslabel~ }
{}
{}
[.~\textbullet\ ]
[.]
```

this part does the subsection as a paragraph (with section number and without page number). I have realized that the problem is the pseudo-code used by `tocloft` for the entries in the TOC

```
{\cftXfont {\cftXpresnum SNUM\cftXaftersnum\hfil} \cftXaftersnumb TITLE}%
{\cftXleader}{\cftXpagefont PAGE}\cftXafterpnum\par
```

I mean, the last command `\par` make impossible to leave two subsection entries in the same textline. Any idea? Another interesting solution is with `etoolbox`, some examples with that package are awesome, but it's not on my hands.

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents*{subsection}[5.4em]{\small}
{\thecontentslabel~ }{}{}[.~\textbullet\ ][.]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter 1}
\section{Test Section 1.1}
\subsection{First Test Subsection}
\subsection{Second Test Subsection}
\subsection{Third Test Subsection}
\subsection{Fourth Test Subsection}
\section{Test Section 1.2}
\subsection{First Test Subsection}
\subsection{Second Test Subsection}

\chapter{Test Chapter 2}
\section{Test Section 2.1}
\subsection{First Test Subsection}
\subsection{Second Test Subsection}
\subsection{Third Test Subsection}
\subsection{Fourth Test Subsection}
\section{Test Section 2.2}
\subsection{First Test Subsection}
\subsection{Second Test Subsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possible solution; `\l@subsection` is redefined to suppress the page number and then, the `etoolbox` package is used to patch `\section` and `\subsection`: each subsection (except the first one) adds `\unskip.~\textbullet\` before the corresponding entry in the ToC, and every `\section` adds the final dot (`\unskip.`) to the last subsection of every section in the ToC:

```
\documentclass{article}          
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newlength\rightmargintoc
\setlength\rightmargintoc{\linewidth}
\addtolength\rightmargintoc{-3em}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@subsection[2]{%
  \parshape 2  0em \rightmargintoc \parindent \rightmargintoc%
  \leavevmode#1}
\makeatother

\pretocmd{\subsection}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}=0\relax
    \else\protect\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\unskip.~\textbullet\ }
  \fi}{}{}{}

\pretocmd{\section}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>0\relax\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\unskip.}
    \else\fi%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\par}}{}{}

\AtEndDocument{\ifnum\value{subsection}>0\relax\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\unskip.}\else\fi}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Test Section One}
\subsection{First Test Subsection}
\subsection{Second Test Subsection}
\subsection{Third Test Subsection}
\subsection{Fourth Test Subsection}

\section{Test Section Two}

\section{Test Section Three}
\subsection{First Test Subsection}
\subsection{Second Test Subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A modification for the `book` document class was requested in the comments:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newlength\rightmargintoc
\setlength\rightmargintoc{\linewidth}
\addtolength\rightmargintoc{-5em}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@subsection[2]{%
  \setlength\@tempdima{3em}%
\parshape 2  2.5em \rightmargintoc \dimexpr\parindent+2.5em\relax \rightmargintoc%
  \leavevmode#1}
\makeatother

\pretocmd{\subsection}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}=0\relax
  \else\protect\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\unskip.~\textbullet\ }
  \fi}{}{}{}

\pretocmd{\chapter}{\addtocontents{toc}{\par}}{}{}

\AtEndDocument{%
\ifnum\value{subsection}>0\relax
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\unskip.}\addtocontents{toc}{\par}
\else\fi}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One One}
\subsection{First Test Subsection}
\subsection{Second Test Subsection}
\subsection{Third Test Subsection}
\subsection{Fourth Test Subsection}
\section{Test Section One Two}
\subsection{First Test Subsection}
\subsection{Second Test Subsection}

\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\section{Test Section Two One}
\subsection{First Test Subsection}
\subsection{Second Test Subsection}

\chapter{Test Chapter Three}
\section{Test Section Three One}
\section{Test Section Three Two}
\subsection{First Test Subsection}
\subsection{Second Test Subsection}

\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting ToC:

[image]

If `hyperref` is loaded, some additional precaution must be taken:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newlength\rightmargintoc
\setlength\rightmargintoc{\linewidth}
\addtolength\rightmargintoc{-5em}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@subsection[2]{%
  \setlength\@tempdima{3em}%
\parshape 2  2.5em \rightmargintoc \dimexpr\parindent+2.5em\relax \rightmargintoc%
  \leavevmode#1}
\makeatother

\pretocmd{\subsection}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}=0\relax
  \else\protect\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\texorpdfstring{\unskip.~\textbullet\ }{}}
  \fi}{}{}{}

\pretocmd{\chapter}{\addtocontents{toc}{\par}}{}{}

\AtEndDocument{%
\ifnum\value{subsection}>0\relax
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\texorpdfstring{\unskip.}{}}\addtocontents{toc}{\par}
\else\fi}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One One}
\subsection{First Test Subsection}
\subsection{Second Test Subsection}
\subsection{Third Test Subsection}
\subsection{Fourth Test Subsection}
\section{Test Section One Two}
\subsection{First Test Subsection}
\subsection{Second Test Subsection}

\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\section{Test Section Two One}
\subsection{First Test Subsection}
\subsection{Second Test Subsection}

\chapter{Test Chapter Three}
\section{Test Section Three One}
\section{Test Section Three Two}
\subsection{First Test Subsection}
\subsection{Second Test Subsection}

\end{document}
```

Here's now an improved version:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=cyan]{hyperref}

\newlength\rightmargintoc
\setlength\rightmargintoc{\linewidth}
\addtolength\rightmargintoc{-7em}

\makeatletter
\def\subsectocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
\parshape 2  2.5em \rightmargintoc \dimexpr\parindent+2.5em\relax \rightmargintoc
\@tempdima#3
\ifdim\lastskip=1sp\relax\ \textbullet~\else\fi{\small#4.}\hskip1sp%
}
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\subsectocline{1}{0em}{3em}}
\makeatother

\pretocmd{\chapter}{\addtocontents{toc}{\par}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\section}{\addtocontents{toc}{\par}}{}{}

\AtEndDocument{%
\ifnum\value{subsection}>0\relax
  \addtocontents{toc}{\par}
\fi}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One One}
\subsection{First Test Subsection}
\subsection{Second Test Subsection}
\subsection{Third Test Subsection}
\subsection{Fourth Test Subsection}
\section{Test Section One Two}
\subsection{First Test Subsection}
\subsection{Second Test Subsection}

\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\section{Test Section Two One}
\subsection{First Test Subsection}
\subsection{Second Test Subsection}

\chapter{Test Chapter Three}
\section{Test Section Three One}
\section{Test Section Three Two}
\subsection{First Test Subsection}
\subsection{Second Test Subsection}

\end{document}
```

The resulting ToC:

[image]

Comment: It works perfect! Thanks Gonzalo Medina, but I need it with the book class. I tried to modify the \chapter command with \pretocmd, similar as you did with \section and \subsection, but my experience is not enough. I've already given a MWE, as @Werner suggests.

Comment: @Gitano I've updated my answer with the modifications requested.

Comment: @Gitano I updated my answer with a solution with `hyperref`. Please let me know of this solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo Medina. I just have some questions. 1) Why is the subsection number placed in a box? Can I get it as: 1.1.1(\@tempdima{3em})This is the first Subsection.? Where \@tempdima{3em} is the length used between the box and the title. I ask that because this spacing is not the same when there are 2 digits on the subsection number. 2) The command \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\small APPENDICES}{\protect\relax}{}} now is causing problems. 3) Some warnings are shown with the hyperref package. I've edited the original the MWE in order to get a tip or suggest of you.

Comment: Thanks, I have already checked! the hyperref warning have disappeared.

Comment: @Gitano 1) requires more work to be done; I'll have to think about it. 2) I'll do some tests and let you know the result. In any case, I'll let you know what have I found.

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo Medina! Just one small detail, the last solution is for the article class, how can I modify for the book class?

Comment: @Gitano Oh, sorry for that. Answer updated.

Comment: @Gitano I didn't experience any problems using `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\small APPENDICES}{\protect\relax}{}}` in my last code. What kind of problems do you get with that line?

Comment: When I add \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\small APPENDICES}{}} to your last code, it show me the next error: Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \contentsline was complete.
&lt;to be read again&gt; 
                   \par 
l.23 \par
         
)

Comment: In addition, if I use \usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}, there is a large spacing between the subsection name and the period. Do you now why? Furthermore, how can I change the font size? I would like to use \small only in the subsection part. Thanks Gonzalo Medina.

Comment: @Gitano the issue with `\addtocontents` can be solved by using `\addtocontents{toc}{\par\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\small APPENDICES}{\protect\relax}{}}`. Regarding the other issues, I'll take a look and let you know.

Comment: @Gitano I updated my answer; I hope this time we're getting closer to the final solution ;-)

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo Medina, everything is perfect. I just updated the MWE in the original questions in order to show you the differences between the spacing of the subsecnumbers and the titles when the chapter number increases. Do you think it is hard to fix that spacing? If the answer is yes, so I will modify the parameter {2.3em}, and it's enough. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Gitano I'll think about the spacing and let you know. Just a little remark: you should edit your question and recover the original MWE; if you want to, you can *add* the new MWE but preserving the older one; otherwise, the question looses meaning since, as it is now, it gives the impression that the new MWE was the starting point.

Comment: You are right! Here it is Gonzalo Medina!