# Patching \chapter command such that all lower sections are set in twocolumn in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, multicol

I've been trying to typeset my ToC like the one in the question [How to make the ToCs part entry in onecolumn while the others are in two columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145041/how-to-make-the-tocs-part-entry-in-one-column-while-the-others-in-two-columns) however, I don't have parts and therefore I want the chapters to be one-column while the `{sub}*sections` are in twocolumn mode.

My approach:

```tex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multicol}

\pretocmd{\chapter}{\protect{\ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\end{multicols}}\fi}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\chapter}{\protect{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\begin{multicols}{2}}}}{}{}

\AtEndDocument{\ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\end{multicols}}\fi}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{FOO}
\section{bar1}
\section{bar2}
\section{bar3}
\section{bar4}

\chapter{BAR}
\section{foo1}
\section{foo2}
\section{foo3}
\section{foo4}
\end{document}
```

However, this is not working properly: The Chapter name disappears.

- Is the approach fundamentally flawed or am I using `\pretocmd` and `\apptocmd` wrong?
- Which approach would **you** use to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Why does the your transformation of [How to make the TOC's part entry in one column while the others in two columns?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145041/5764) not work? That's because of the way `\part` and `\chapter` work. They don't capture the arguments themselves, but instead calls other helper macros to do that. As such, inserting elements "at the end of the `\chapter` command" actually interfere with the other parts of the macros.

Here's how you need to patch it instead:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tocloft,etoolbox,multicol}

\pretocmd{\chapter}{\ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\end{multicols}}\fi}{}{}
\apptocmd{\chapterheadendvskip}{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\begin{multicols}{2}}}{}{}
\AtEndDocument{\ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\end{multicols}}\fi}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{FOO}
\section{bar1}
\section{bar2}
\section{bar3}
\section{bar4}

\chapter{BAR}
\section{foo1}
\section{foo2}
\section{foo3}
\section{foo4}
\end{document}
```

`\chapterheadendvskip` is the last macro executed by but `\chapter` and `\chapter*` (actually `\@@makechapterhead` and `\@@makeschapterhead`) after the heading is set. It's the appropriate place to insert the `multicols` environment in the ToC.

---

If you're using a sectional package like [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec), the above patch doesn't work. The reason is obvious - sectional packages typically redefine the way the sectional macros work, making the `\patchcmd` fail (either because of a changed command, or because the change is never seen due to the package suggesting a different route through the sectional unit construction). Here's one work-around when using `titlesec` - use the "after code" section to insert the `\begin{multicol}{2}` in the ToC:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{multicol,etoolbox}
\usepackage{titletoc,titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{127,0,0}
\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{169,121,69}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}

\titleformat{\chapter}% Command
  [block]% Shape
  {\Huge\bfseries\color{myred}}% Format
  {\centering\protect{\color{myyellow}\thechapter\hfil}}% Label
  {1em}% Sep
  {}% Before-Code
  [\ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\begin{multicols}{2}}\fi]% After-Code

\pretocmd{\chapter}{\ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\end{multicols}}\fi}{}{}
\AtEndDocument{\ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\end{multicols}}\fi}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{FOO}
\section{bar1}
\section{bar2}
\section{bar3}
\section{bar4}

\chapter{BAR}
\section{foo1}
\section{foo2}
\section{foo3}
\section{foo4}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is unexpected. I assumed that a command named `apptocmd` can actually append code to a command [meaning that appended code is executed after the original command has fully finished]. Your solution does work as advertised, however, my actual use case is much more involved using several other packages (hyperref, titletoc to name a few which I expect to modify the `\chapter` command). Is there a fail-safe approach to find the last command executed by `\chapter` (i.e. the one which needs to be patched)? It appears that patching `\chapterheadendvskip` in my non-MWE example has no effect: [1/2]

Comment: The `Master.toc` file contains the ToC entries and the `\end{multicols}` forms but not the `\begin{multicols}{2}` forms. [2/2]

Comment: @elemakil: Two things; (1) Post an example that replicates the problem; (2) `\apptocmd` does exactly what you say, but when executing `\chapter{<chapter name>}` the macro `\chapter` doesn't actually grab the argument `{<chapter name>}`. That's done by another macro. That's why you appendage to the command `\chapter` isn't actually correct. One would have to follow the trail of how the macros expand in order to find the correct/appropriate location for the insertion. Mine led me to `\chapterheadendvskip`.

Comment: You can find an updated example [here](http://pastebin.com/dfnZqwNQ). Could you explain what's the best way to "follow the trail" in order to find the command appropriate for patching? I think understanding how to solve this problem is much more important than the actual solution (not that I'd complain about being given the solution ;-) ).

Comment: @elemakil: The reason why my solution doesn't work is because you're actually using a sectional package ([`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) in this case) which overwrites many of the sectional commands and how they interact with one another. Are you someone who enjoys debugging code? :) I'll update my code to accommodate the interaction with `titlesec`.

Comment: @elemakil: Note that using [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) in conjunction with the [KOMA-script classes](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) is not recommended (check your `.log` for the warning message during compilation). Also, don't mix ToC-related packages like [`titletoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) and [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft).